# How to create virtualenv with specific downloaded python version

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

I know there are some similar questions,but it is really hard for me to finish it.

I'm trying to create a virtualenv with python 3.7.7 in windows.

I have a downloaded python 3.7.7

```
C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python-3.7.8-embed-amd64
```

Since I can built a virtualenv using:

```
python3 -m venv myenv
```

So I tried to modify it ,so that it can match specific python version:

```
python3 -m C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python-3.7.8-embed-amd64\python.exe myenv
```

But it failed:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C:\\Users\\willi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\python-3')
```

Any friends can teach me how to build a virtualenv with python 3.7.7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: Usually you'd need to have python on your Environment path Variable. After that you can use `python -m venv myenv` or `python3 -m venv myenv`. I recommend downloading and installing python from microsoft store. But here is a tutorial from https://realpython.com/installing-python/

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't installed virtual environment in your local python

```
pip install virtualenv
```

and follow your steps. Stil, find the error. Try doing below methods, I think you will get your answer-

in command prompt

```
pip install virtualenv
```

go to the location, where you want to create your environment

```
cd location
virtualenv project_env_name
```

Now, you will find a python env in the desired location, Then go to scripts

```
cd project_env_name/scripts
activate
```

You will enter the environment you created. while leaving the environment, do

```
deactivate
```

To leave the environment.

This method works if you want to create the same python version environment as python version in your machine.
If you want to create an environment of the different version, you need to install the python of that version.